# Behaviour or -EFAULT, Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, segmentation-fault

I am running some test cases that I know will cause my program (running in kernel space) to return an `-EFAULT`. Here is the code that returns the fault:

```
for (index = 0; index < size; index++){
        //copy_from_user checks to make sure input parameter is valid. Returns 0 on success
        if(copy_from_user(&currentArrayElement, &data[index], sizeof(long))) {
            printk("copy from user error \n");          
            return -EFAULT;
            printk("copy from user error: just returned efault");   
        } 
        else {
        //parameter is ok
        if (currentArrayElement < kernelStats.min)
            kernelStats.min = currentArrayElement;

        if (currentArrayElement > kernelStats.max)
            kernelStats.max = currentArrayElement;

        kernelStats.sum += currentArrayElement;     
        }
    }

    //print debugging info
    printk("Min: %ld Max: %ld Sum: %ld\n", kernelStats.min, kernelStats.max, kernelStats.sum);
```

When the first if block is triggered, it seems like the `EFAULT` is being returned, since the "copy from user error: just returned efault" doesn't print. However, rather than exiting the function entirely, the debugging info at the bottom is printed. It seems to print whether there is an `EFAULT` or not. Is this an idiosyncrasy of `EFAULT`? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Too long for a comment.)*

`return` will do what you expect it to irrespective of the parameters.

I would bet you are calling the function more than once. On the first time you are seeing `copy from user error`, and on the second time you are seeing the debugging info.

To test this theory, put an extra `printk` in right at the top.